# How can I make sure all branches are in the MASTER?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am finally getting my head around Git, using tutorials I found on SourceTree's website.

Previously, I created a new branch after each commit when it resulted in a new upload to the App Store.  Now, I understand that all commits from the local -> remote repository go to the MASTER branch on the remote.

If this is correct, then am I safe to delete all of the branches, both local and remote other than the MASTER?  Here is what it looks like when viewed in SourceTree:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like what you really wanted to create were tags (names for a particular commit that never change) rather than branches (places to do additional work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot, you have a completely linear history (no extra commits on the branches after they were created), so deleting all of the branches other than `master` should not lose any commits. If you want to keep track of certain commits with special names (e.g. to remember where a release was made), you might consider tags (`git tag`) instead.

Comment: Thanks Amber...that's exactly what I was attempting to do... (haven't gotten to tag's yet...) :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be safe if you only want to save MASTER branch; but think about it, GiT has a store schema without redundant files, so that branches are not wasting space (taking in account there are no big binaries that were deleted at MASTER branch or something similar).

I recommend you not to delete nothing, maybe you find some bug in MASTER branch and you can go backwards to another branch (I hope no, mate ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for the general case with

```
git rev-list --all ^master
```

or, prettier,

```
git log --decorate --oneline --all ^master
```

`--all` says "every commit reachable from any reference", `^master` says "except for anything you can reach from `master`".